# setup ssh encryption keys

Tags: ssh, password, security

Here is the situation:
I have 4 Linux servers. `/home` is same for all the four servers. (It's a network drive). I want to setup a password-less SSH via setting up encryption keys. I created RSA key pair using `ssh-keygen`.
Because the `/home` is same for all users. So I added the public key to authorized key for `$HOME/.ssh` directory

But when I try to ssh to these servers, it still asks for the password.

Help please!

Comment: Did you set your permissions right on the files in the .ssh directory. The easiest is to delete them on remote and then use `ssh-copy-id`.

Comment: I moved key pair to home directory, now I have oct15, oct15.pub in $HOME. then "ssh-copy-id -i $HOME/oct15.pub user@machine2". It shows it did something n asks me to check "ssh user@machine2". It still doesnot work. It asks for password

Comment: Please note /home is same for user on all servers.

Comment: can you please run `ssh -v` to one of the servers, then add the output to your question?

Comment: Please confirm that the password request comes from the *remote*. That is, it reads `user@remote's password:`, not `Enter password for private key:`. Also please add the output of `ls -al ~/.ssh` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter `ssh hostname` SSH tries password-based auth by default. So you have to enter an additional option to the command:

```
ssh -i .ssh/private-key-of-host hostname
```

After the `-i` option should be the filename of your key. Now you can login without entering a password.

However there another possibility: You can have a configuration file in `.ssh/config`. Enter here:

```
Host Foo
  HostName 123.45.67.89
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/private-key-of-host
```

Now you can enter `ssh Foo` and SSH tries to connect to the host mentioned in `HostName` (can be a IP address or a hostname) with the key from `IdentityFile`.

Comment: There is no need to pass `-i` when you use one of the default keyfiles (`identity`, `id_rsa`, etc.). Ssh will try PKI-based authentication in preference to password authentication.